# Android Studio NDK/SDK version error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, android-sdk-tools

Hi_all !

I switched to Android Studio yesterday, I was able to compile my "cocos2d-x game" yesterday. But after adding too more ABI’s (**armeabi-v7** and **x86**) to my `Application.mk` and `gradle.properties`, it gave me these errors when running the game:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
.....
Android NDK: android-10 is unsupported. Using minimum supported version android-14.    
.....

BUILD FAILED in 4m 45s
```

Now what can I do to run my game like before? Thanks.

Comment: Update the version as per suggestion. `android-10` and `android-14` are very old versions you shouldn't have any problem switching from `10` to `14`

Comment: @pleft Which files should I edit to update the version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the version as per suggestion. `android-10` and `android-14` are very old versions you shouldn't have any problem switching from `10` to `14`

Check your `Application.mk` and add or change (if it is referring `android-10`) the line:

```
 APP_PLATFORM := android-14
```